# How to use a .ttf file in HTML deprecated <font> tag

Tags: html, http, fonts, deprecated

I downloaded a font called Roboto-Thin.ttf and I referenced using
`<link rel="preload" href="Roboto-Thin.ttf" type="font/ttf" as="font" />`

It worked, because on the Network tab in DevTools I see the file being requested to the server, and the server successfully responds with the .ttf file to the client.

Now I tried to use like this: `<font face="Roboto-Thin">[Some text]</font>` and `<font face="roboto">[Some text]</font>`, but the text seems to be the default Arial or Calibri or TimesNewRoman(or whatever the default one is). It is cert that it isn't Roboto. But if I try to use the deprecated  tag with a windows font: "face=verdana", it works. So if the .ttf file loads successfully and the HTML  tag is avalaible even if it is deprecated, I don't know why it doesn't work. I want to mention that **I want to make this work with HTML  tag on purpose, so if you answer using the any other method it doesn't help me**.

I have the .ttf installed on the server. The browser request it with success: [image]

[image]

And the HTML processor supports all HTML5 features.

Comment: `<font>` being deprecated for many years means that implementations are not updated to cater with new features like downloadable fonts. If your HTML processor does not support CSS, it will most likely not support custom TTF fonts either. If you're expected to be able to use custom fonts, perhaps you need to install them on the server.

Comment: I have them installed on the server. I edited the thread, take a look again!

Comment: Can we have more information about your toolset? I presume there is no browser involved, so when I talked about installing fonts on server I assumed that same server was running the HTML rendering engine.

Comment: What does your screenshot illustrate? Putting a font file in a folder in a web server to be delivered does not have anything to do with installing fonts on the server.

Comment: Are you trying to make Brave use downloadable fonts in `<font>` tags? What for? I really doubt that neither Google nor Brave have spent resources implementing that.

Comment: What do you mean, installing the font on the server? The server is my local machine (Windows 10), and the server is a simple C# HttpListener

Comment: I'm trying to do something with 0% CSS, even I the browser or the server can handle css, I want to do a beauty site without CSS

Comment: Forcefully using `<font>` in a regular browser does not serve any purpose in 2023, I took it for granted that you had an HTML to PDF rendering tool or some custom reporting software.

Comment: "I want to do a beauty site without CSS" - Well, without CSS you cannot do most of the things that CSS was created to accomplish. For example, downloadable fonts.

Comment: No, the setup is very simple. C# Console App with HttpListener. An index.html page that gets delivered to the browser, a script.js that also gets delivered, a favicon.ico that works and a ttf that I want to put in use without using CSS.

Comment: Fine, so the final answer is that it is impossible what I'm trying to achieve, correct?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer because I haven't inspected the source code of Chromium or Gecko but it wouldn't make sense to maintain deprecated  tags from the 1990s and add new features to them.

Comment: You would at least need `<style>`  tag to include a proper **`@font-face`** rule mapping font files to specific **font-family, weight and style properties** – a pre loaded font file  alone doesn't specify any font file to property relations. I totally agree with @Álvaro González: unless you need a super-legacy-backwards-compatibility (let's say maintaining a quirky windows embedded system) there is no sane reason to avoid css at any cost (even ie6 ... kind of supported it). If your ultimate goal is to provide a perfectly self contained HTML document – just inline css styles.